# VBA Data Validation Drop Down List, Allow Free Text Also?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a section of code found from elsewhere on the web that allows multiple selections from a list generated in the 'Data Validation' options. It works well and it should really help in a data gathering exercise that I am doing. I'd like to make the process as painless for the end user by allowing lots of selections to speed up their work.

However, I was wondering if there were changes that could be made to it to allow users to also enter free text as well. One of the other problems that's apparent is there is a line of code which when a cell value changes (such as someone typing free text), the new value is appended to the existing value. This causes the cell to duplicate it's contents even just from hitting 'Return' etc

Example of code "Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue"

The event is triggered after a cell's content is modified. When entering free text, Excel sees this as a modification and triggers the "Worksheet_Change" event. At this point, the oldValue is the entire list of previously selected items, and the newValue is the free text just entered. The code concatenates these together, causing a duplication.

So my questions are is there a way to allow free text entry and not cause the duplicative effect. Thank you.

The code is as follows:

````
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Destination As Range)
Dim rngDropdown As Range
Dim oldValue As String
Dim newValue As String
Dim DelimiterType As String
DelimiterType = vbCrLf
Dim DelimiterCount As Integer
Dim TargetType As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim arr() As String
 
If Destination.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
 
Set rngDropdown = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitError
 
If rngDropdown Is Nothing Then GoTo exitError
 
TargetType = 0
    TargetType = Destination.Validation.Type
    If TargetType = 3 Then  ' is validation type is "list"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        newValue = Destination.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldValue = Destination.Value
        Destination.Value = newValue
        If oldValue <> "" Then
            If newValue <> "" Then
                If oldValue = newValue Or oldValue = newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") Or oldValue = newValue & DelimiterType Then ' leave the value if there is only one in the list
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, DelimiterType, "")
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, DelimiterType & newValue) Or InStr(1, oldValue, " " & newValue & DelimiterType) Then
                    arr = Split(oldValue, DelimiterType)
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(newValue, arr, 0)) = 0 Then
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                        Else:
                    Destination.Value = ""
                    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    If arr(i) <> newValue Then
                        Destination.Value = Destination.Value & arr(i) & DelimiterType
                    End If
                    Next i
                Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - Len(DelimiterType))
                End If
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, newValue, "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                Else
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                End If
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) ' remove extra commas and spaces
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""))
                If Destination.Value <> "" Then
                    If Right(Destination.Value, 2) = DelimiterType Then  ' remove delimiter at the end
                        Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - 2)
                    End If
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, DelimiterType) = 1 Then ' remove delimiter as first characters
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "", 1, 1)
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) = 1 Then
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "", 1, 1)
                End If
                DelimiterCount = 0
                For i = 1 To Len(Destination.Value)
                    If InStr(i, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                        DelimiterCount = DelimiterCount + 1
                    End If
                Next i
                If DelimiterCount = 1 Then ' remove delimiter if last character
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "")
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
 
exitError:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
 
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)```
````

Comment: If the user want to write free text have to delete the existing and write the new, and the code will add the old value...

Comment: Yes at present if the user types or selects something from the drop down menu, then uses the Alt-Return or attempts use enter in the cell formula bar. The contents will be duplicated.

Comment: If the cell has a value e.g    aaaa bbbb and the user want to add 123 MUST SELECT ALL the contents of the cell and after write: 123. Press Enter, and the cell now have aaa bbbb 123. THE USER  BEFORE WRITE ANYTHING HAVE TO SELECT THE EXISTING VALUE IN CELL.

Comment: Might be easier to manage if you add an "Other..." selection to the end of the validation list, then pop up an input box where the user can enter the value they want.  It's not clear how your user could later *remove* that value though.

Answer (score 1):

An image shows the steps to take when you want to write something and not duplicate the existing value. The critical point is to select the contents before you type... as you type the old text will disappear, but will reappear when you press ENTER.

[image]

Comment: Yes I can see that is a viable method of adding things to cells but it's not intuitive to the end user. Also if you wish to delete something that you've added the "Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue" component will kick in and cause duplications of the entire cell contents.